# How do I read tables using shiny package?

Tags: r, shiny

I am really new to R and shiny.

I am trying to read a dataset using the shiny package.
Originally in R, I would simply use

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
  
  T <- data$TEMP         
  X <- data$TSUSC        
  Cs <- data$CSUSC        
  Ns <- data$NSUSC
```

And then manipulate and use the variables T, X, Cs and Ns.

Now, with shiny, it doesn`t seem so intuitive.
I am able to upload a see the table as a whole, using

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    
    req(input$file1)
    
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote)
      },
      error = function(e) {
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )
    
    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    } else { return(df)}
    
  })
}
```

However, I do not know how to assign variables to each column and then manipulate them.
How can I do something similar to

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
  
  T <- data$TEMP         
  X <- data$TSUSC        
  Cs <- data$CSUSC        
  Ns <- data$NSUSC
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In the **shiny**, if you want to read an object and use it afterwards (reactively), you have to load using `reactive()`. Something like this would help you:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  # load the data and save it as a reactive object
  data = reactive({
    file = input$file1
    if (is.null(file)) {
      stop('Wrong input!')
    } else {
      read.csv(file$datapath, input$file1$datapath,
               header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
               quote = input$quote)
    }
  })
  # now you can call the loaded data and render it
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    if(input$disp == 'head') {
      return(head(data()))
    } else {
      return(df)
    }
  })
}
```